# Disable one feature file from running in parallel with other features in c# using SpecFlow

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, specflow

I have a few feature files that run in parallel using specflow
I want to disable one of the features from running in parallel with others.
Tried adding addNonParallelizableMarkerForTags field to specflow.json but it didn't work
Would to have any other ideas how to do that

tnx

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include information about how you run these tests? Do you run them from Visual Studio? Using `dotnet test`? Using `nunit-console.exe`?